# How can I get a post attribute in a view class in Django?

Tags: python, django, url, post, view

I want to redirect to another view after a successful update, this is my code

Template

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <h3>{% trans "Editar información" %}</h3>
   <form method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
         {{ form|crispy }}
       <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="{% trans 'Confirmar' %}" />
       <input type="hidden" name="pk" value="{{ request.user.id }}" />

    </form>
</div>
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required as LR

url(r'^editperfil/(?P<pk>\d+)/$' , LR(EditarPerfil.as_view()), {}, name="editar_perfil"),
url(r'^edituser/(?P<pk>\d+)/$' , LR(EditarUsuario.as_view()), {}, name="editar_user"),
```

This is my view

```
class EditarUsuario(UpdateView):
    model=User
    form_class=EditUserForm
    template_name = "editarUsuario.html"

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('editar_perfil', args=(), kwargs={'pk':"pk" })
```

I need the pk parameter but I don't know how I can get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

class EditarUsuario(UpdateView):
    model=User
    form_class=EditUserForm
    template_name = "editarUsuario.html"

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('editar_perfil', args = (self.object.id,))
```